# debugShowCheckedModeBanner Not remove debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to remove the debug banner from my application and I added `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` in my main.dart and every activity but still showing the debug banner.

Main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intrackapp/login/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:khalti_flutter/khalti_flutter.dart';
import 'login/firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp( MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return KhaltiScope(
       publicKey: "test_public_key_6ddec90a98d44awe4d84e2c58fc172490a",
       builder: (context, navKey) {
         return MaterialApp(
          // debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
           navigatorKey: navKey,
           localizationsDelegates: const[KhaltiLocalizations.delegate],
           theme: ThemeData(
             primaryColor: Colors.grey, // Set default color to blue
           ),

               debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
               home: SplashScreen(),
         );
       }
     );
  }
}
```

The major issue is `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` is not removing the debug banner because the debug banner shows on every page. How to remove the debug banner?

Comment: can you add the code of other screens?

Comment: don't worry about it.  it goes away in release mode.  And in debug mode, you and your beta testers should be reminded that the code is much slower than release mode.  Historical trivia: originally, that banner said "slow". :)

Answer (score 2):

you commented the debugShowCheckedModeBanner line,
remove the comment slashes. (//)

Comment: It is Uncomment in code

Answer (score 1):

If you are use the MaterialApp widget in all app screen so please make sure in all screen widget debugShowCheckedModeBanner is true or false.

If it's true so please set the false of debugShowCheckedModeBanner.

Comment: It is false an uncomment but also there is debug banner in app